# Animating dimensions in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to animate the height of a dataview, but it's currently just sliding the panel around the viewport instead of keeping it in place and changing it's height. The code is as follows:

```
Ext.Anim.run(el, 'slide', {
  from: { height: height },
  to: { height: newHeight },
  out: false,
  direction: 'up',
  easing: 'ease-out',
  duration: 1000
});
```

For instance, height=200, newHeight=100 will result in the dataview dropping immediately so that it's top is at 200px below the viewport, and then animating back to the top of the viewport.

How can I get it to change the height? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `Ext.Animator.run` instead:

```
Ext.Animator.run({
    element: dataview.element,
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'ease-in',
    preserveEndState: true,
    from: {
        height: dataview.element.getHeight()
    },
    to: {
        height: 100
    }
});
```

And within a full example:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {
        var dataview = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
            fullscreen: true,
            style: 'background:red',
            store: {
                fields: ['text'],
                data: [
                    { text: 'one' },
                    { text: 'two' },
                    { text: 'three' }
                ]
            },
            itemTpl: '{text}'
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'top',
            handler: function() {
                Ext.Animator.run({
                    element: dataview.element,
                    duration: 500,
                    easing: 'ease-in',
                    preserveEndState: true,
                    to: {
                        height: 100
                    },
                    from: {
                        height: dataview.element.getHeight()
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is it just me, or are there not any docs for Animator?

Comment: Currently, no. The reason was that we (Sencha) wanted to look at it in more detail in 2.1, and perhaps change how it works. We didn't want to break peoples applications with the 2.1 update, so we resorted to keeping the existing animation system (Ext.Anim) which is buggy (as you have experienced) until we fix up Ext.Animator. For now, your best bet is to look at the source and look at the available properties. Your best start is looking at `src/fx/animation/Abstract.js`.

Comment: Thanks again. Consider Animator getting my vote for Sencha 2.1! Will make my app much more slick.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add comments, I'll have to put this as a separate answer.  I just wanted to add to what rdougan said and show how you can catch the animation end event.  I find it's necessary in the above situation because Sencha Touch's component.getTop/Left/Height/Width() functions return incorrect values after an animation such as the one shown.

```
dataview.setHeight(dataview.element.getHeight()); // you may or may not need this

console.log('height before\t', dataview.getHeight());

var a = new Ext.fx.Animation({
    element: dataview.element,
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'ease-in',
    preserveEndState: true,
    from: {
        height: dataview.element.getHeight()
    },
    to: {
        height: 100
    }
});

a.on('animationend', function (animation, element, isInterrupted) {
    console.log('height before\t', dataview.getHeight());
    dataview.setHeight(dataview.element.getHeight());
    console.log('height set\t', dataview.getHeight());
});

Ext.Animator.run(a);
```

I left in some logging so you can see just what I mean.  This example was written against ST 2.1 RC2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean utility function you can use to accomplish this

```
function animatron (target, prop, duration, to, from, easing) {
    // return if no target or prop
    if (target == null || prop == null) { return; }

    // defaults
    if (duration == null) { duration = 250; }
    if (to == null) { to = 0; }
    if (from == null) { from = target.getHeight(); }
    if (easing == null) { easing = 'ease-out'; }

    // to property
    var t = {};
    t[prop] = to;

    // from property
    var f = {};
    f[prop] = from;

    // Animation Options
    var opts = {
        duration: duration,
        easing: easing,
        element: target.element,
        from: f,
        preserveEndState: true,
        to: t
    };

    // Animation Object
    var anime = new Ext.fx.Animation(opts);

    // On animationend Event
    anime.on('animationend', function (animation, element, isInterrupted) {
        // Hide the target if the to is 0
        if (to == 0 && (prop == 'height' || prop == 'width')) {
            if (!isInterrupted) { target.hide(); }
        }

        // Update property if width or height
        if (prop == 'height') { target.setHeight(to); }
        if (prop == 'width') { target.setWidth(to); }

        // Dispatch 'animated' event to target
        target.fireEvent('animated', animation, element, to, from, isInterrupted);
    });

    // Show the target if it's hidden and to isn't 0
    if (target.getHidden() == true && to != 0) { target.show(); }

    // Run the animation
    Ext.Animator.run(anime);
}
```

You can listen for the 'animated' event on the target element

```
animatron(dataview, 'height', 500, 0);
dataview.addListener('animated', function (animation, element, to, from, isInterrupted) {
    console.log('animation ended');
    console.log('interrupted: '+ isInterrupted);
});
```