# On Animation end, component snaps back

Tags: animation, sencha-touch-2

I'm using the animation below to slide my toolbar up and it slides up, but it doesn't stay. It slides back to its original position. Is this normal behavior?......if so do I have to explicitly set the new top value for the toolbar? Also in my toolbar config , I specify: top: 1536.

```
Code:
Ext.Anim.run(toolbar,'slide',{
                        direction: 'up',
                        duration: 1000,
                        from:{top:1536},
                        to:{top:1432}
                     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work

```
Ext.Animator.run({
    element: toolbar,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'ease-in',
    preserveEndState: true,
    from: {top:1536},
    to: {top:1432}
});
```

Comment: but why doesn't Ext.Anim.run work? Also is Ext.Animator.run documented anywhere?

Comment: This is a work in progress api. Might become official in 2.1. This post from one of the sencha dev will give more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872730/animating-dimensions-in-sencha-touch-2

Comment: also the after option to execute a function after the animation end does not fire